# Why is SQL Server returning database name in lowercase?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored proc in SQL Server where I'm using db_name() to get the name of my database and then put it into an xml string as seen below (abbreviated version). When I run my application, it appears the SiteID is the lowercase version of the database name, which is causing me problems later. So SiteID is abc123 instead of ABC123, like I see in SSMS. When i do an ad-hoc query to select db_name() it shows up as ABC123. Does anyone know why it would do this? Or if I'm wrong about it being db_name() doing the lowercase conversion?

```
select 
db_name() SiteID, 
@audit_id audit_id
for xml path ('ChangeRequest')
```

Comment: `db_name()` *should* return the same value, from an Application or SSMS directly.. expanding that out, the result of the full queries (including `for xml`) *should* also be the same.

Comment: I could be wrong, maybe it's lowercasing it somewhere else. Just can't find out how

Comment: Does the connection string use ABC123 (or abc134) for the Default Catalog / DB? I doubt this matters (as `use casingherewontaffectdbname`), but..

Comment: depends of the server collation... usually setup to be non-case sensitive

Comment: Not sure which connection string you are talking about. In master.dbo.sysdatabases, it shows it as ABC123. The collation for this database is the same as others where I'm not having this problem- SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @Kelly Why don't you use `SELECT UPPER(DB_NAME())` while you need it always upper case

Comment: in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, the "CI" means case-insensitive.

Comment: I will be doing something like that, Sami. But I have about 100 near identical databases- want to get the bottom as to why this is happening for only one of them.